# How do I stop someone from using our app?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, authentication

Our iOS app has a kind of chat room, messaging service built into it, which is reflected on our website.

Sometimes we get a few users who come on just to stir up trouble, but lately there's been a few who we just can't shake. On the web we can restrict their IP, and recently we've been blocking them through the app via device ID.

Which worked for a while until they figured out that reinstalling the app reset it.

Is there anyway at all to identify these people, and permanently restrict their access?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can store the device ID in the [keychain](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Security/Conceptual/keychainServConcepts/01introduction/introduction.html), that way they have the same id even after deleting and reinstalling the app.

Comment: That's brillaint. Didn't even think of that. Any drawbacks?

Comment: Not at all. As long as they don`t buy a new device ;)

Comment: I just thought of one, if they sell the device and the new owner wants to use your app, he can`t because of the same id.

Comment: If they decided to sell the device I would expect the new user to probably restore to factory settings which should wipe the keychain.

Comment: They probably will, so i see no downsides at all.

Comment: Be very careful with this.  Apple will no longer accept apps that use `[UIDevice uniqueIdentifier]` to identify a specific device.  See [iOS 7.0 Release Notes](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/General/RN-iOSSDK-7.0/).  The replacement for `uniqueIdentifier` is `[UIDevice identifierForVendor]`, which has this important caveat in the UIDevice Class Reference:  "The value changes when the user deletes all of that vendor’s apps from the device and subsequently reinstalls one or more of them."

Comment: @Axeva Or he just creates his own uuid, in this case he won`t have any problems.